# Connect AWS ACL but "no resources found"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, acl, web-application-firewall

I have read every AWS tutorial on this, but cannot seem to connect my ACL to the Load Balancer I created for a single EC2 Instance.

I'm simply trying to protect the single EC2 instance with a WAF.

The ACL is created, there are a group of rules, but when I click "Add association" and select Application Load Balancer, there are "No Resources Found"

The instance is running, the LB status is "In Service", they are *in the same region*  but I cannot connect it all.

**NOTE:** I do not want to run CloudFront for this project.  Any guidance welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Is your load balancer "Classic" or "Application" load balancer? AWS WAF will work on ALB (Application Load Balancer), API Gateway, CF. Also, you cannot deploy WAF directly on EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you, I had not considered this. I believe it may be in "classic" Will follow up upon result.

Comment: THIS WORKED.  There are incorrect tutorials out there that do not account for this.  IF you want to connect a WAF ACL to your EC2 instance, the EC2 instance has to be connected to a "Load Balancer" but specifically an APPLICATION Load Balancer.  From there the ACL you've created can 'associate' to the ALB.